# How to include return value 0 in same tabel Mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

i've some problem with query mysql,

```
CREATE TABLE `usulan` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sumber_dana` enum('APBD-OPD','APBD Kelurahan','APBD Prov/APBN','Non APBN/APBD') DEFAULT 'APBD-OPD');

INSERT INTO `usulan` (`id`, `sumber_dana`) VALUES
(1, 'APBD-OPD'),
(2, 'APBD Prov/APBN');
```

I want to return include 0, like this

```
sumber_dana | total
APBD-OPD | 1
APBD Kelurahan | 0
APBD Prov/APBN | 1
Non APBN/APBD | 0
```

Please help me guys, and thank's

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089807/getting-the-values-of-a-mysql-enum-using-only-sql

Comment: You can find the enum vaues in information_schema.columns. - SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,
  column_type
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'ENUM' after you have tided them up you will need to split them into seperate rows and join to your table,