# Is it possible to select all the individual strings of SET in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Example: The column Gender in a MySQL table have been defined as a SET, with possible values 'Male', 'Female', 'Other', 'Not Specified'. I want to show the same options in a Selectbox on a PHP page.

**Question: Is it possible for me to read the options specified in the SET using MySQL and use PHP to display them?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622481/how-to-get-available-values-for-set-field would that help ?

Comment: Yup, that definitely did help. Thank @Falt4rm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query( "SHOW COLUMNS FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME WHERE Field = 'YOUR_FIELD_NAME'");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
preg_match("/^set\(\'(.*)\'\)$/", $row['Type'], $matches);
$set = explode("','", $matches[1]);
```